# Write C++ code in C style

Tags: c++, c, gcc

If we want to write a module in C and have to compile it as C++ with `g++`, is it OK to develop a piece of code in C++ without any own classes, only using "global / static functions" as in C? So, simply said, to code C in C++ (with only few system header changes etc.)

Comment: @Oliver: It's close enough that many projects will compile without modification, but no, C is not a subset of C++. Consider the trivial case that any C program that uses `class` as a variable name won't compile as C++.

Comment: When handling those header changes, consider using `#ifdef __cplusplus` or equivalent. With that, you may be able to get your code to compile on both with no issues at all.

Comment: @PhilLello: A ⊂ B and B ⊃ A are exactly the same thing, and both false in this instance.

Comment: You may want to read [this article](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) on differences between C and C++.

Comment: Note that if you just say `gcc x.cpp` or `g++ x.c`, you will actually end up using the "correct" compiler (i.e. C++ for `x.cpp` and C for `x.c`). The name of the program is just convenience. So I assume that you will have a genuine C++ program file that you want to "write like C"?

Comment: **C++ is _not_ a superset of C.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it's generally a good idea because C++ enforces stronger type-checking than C.

Comment: yes `stronger type-checking` is important. `Variable Length Array` point can also be added.

Comment: stronger type checking? in the intersection of C and C++? That's an urban myth. The only difference there is that in C you can more easily convert pointers to `void*` but that's all in which C++ is more restrictive. On the other hand C is more restrictive on checking `const`ness of pointer arguments. So I think that that classification is not of much help.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Try running this through your C compiler: `const int a = 0; int* b = &a; float* b = &a;`. If your compiler was written by sensible people, it will emit a couple of warnings. It can only emit warnings because the code is valid C (even C99, AFAIK). Yes, the fact that good compilers raise the alarm makes this less of a slam-dunk, but I'd much rather a compiler that enforces rather than suggests correct behaviour. I don't get the const-ness argument. If you're referring to the automatic removal of const-ness from string literals, that's just a C-compatibility wart.

Comment: @JensGustedt: For a real-world demonstration of this, while testing the point you made in your answer about `sizeof('a')`, I accidentally wrote `fprintf("sizeof('a') == %d", sizeof('a'));`. The gcc version gave me a warning, which I ignored, and then a bus error at runtime; g++ said, `error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘FILE*’ ...`.

Comment: How would be assigning an `int const*` to a `float*` valid in C? This is a constraint violation. It seems you simply don't know enough about C99. And the first rule in C is simply that you shouldn't ignore warnings that the compiler gives you it is as simple as that. If you need that in addition just use `-Werror`. My version of gcc (called `c99`) spits me three scarry warning on your bogus `fprintf` line, how can you have the ideas to ignore these.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Firstly, there's a mountain of code in the wild that was written for pre-C99, and several current compilers — notably gcc — don't compile C99 by default. In fact, even running the `const int*` to `float*` conversion with `gcc -std=c99 ...` produced a warning, not an error. Secondly, you missed my point. C (as opposed to your choice of C compiler) doesn't have the same type safety as C++. Therefore, C++ compilers will never, ever compile such bogus casts, whereas C compilers have to be loaded up with options to avoid trouble. I chose the word "enforces" carefully.

Answer (score 5):

While most C source code will compile as C++ code without any changes, certain language differences prevent C++ from being a strict superset of C.

### Valid in C, but invalid in C++

- C++ has new keywords (class,template,virtual and so on), you should n't use it it your C code if you intent to compile it by C++ compiler
- C++ has much restrictive typecasting:

Valid in C but invalid in C++

```
int *j = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

Valid in both:

```
int *j = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

- Enumeration constants (enum values) are always of type int in C, whereas they are distinct types in C++ and may have size different from that of int.
- C allows struct, union, and enum types to be declared in function prototypes, whereas C++ does not.

### Behave differently in C and C++

- Character literals such as 'a' are of type int in C and of type char in C++
- The static keyword is used in C to restrict a function or global variable to file scope (internal linkage). This is also valid in C++, although C++ deprecates this usage in favor of anonymous namespaces (which are not available in C). Also, C++ implicitly treats any const global as file scope unless it is explicitly declared extern, unlike C in which extern is the default. Conversely, inline functions in C are of file scope whereas they have external linkage by default in C++.

You can find the exhaustive differents list, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to do a couple of things other than *only use functions*, in particular you should mark all your functions as `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling and enforce C calling conventions (and incidentally block you from overloading). If you want to be able to compile it in C, you will have to qualify types with `struct` when declaring variables (`enum` for enumerations), or provide the appropriate typedefs...

Alternatively, you can add `-x c` to the compiler options to tell g++ to compile the code as C (if you are not able to change the command line from `g++` to `gcc`, you might not be able to add compiler flags either...)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is only necessary if you intend to interoperate with code compiled with a C compiler. System libraries are generally nice enough to wrap their stuff in `extern "C" { ... }` already.

Answer (score 3):

You can "write C++" in many styles -- that's one of the fundamental strengths of the language. That includes a strictly procedural, flat programming style common to C programs. You'll still be writing C++, but the code should end up looking very familiar to any C programmer.

Strictly speaking, you will have to use the C++ headers `<cstdio>` etc, and all your C library functions are in the `std` namespace. Perhaps this is one of the few legitimate situations where you should use `using namespace std;`! :-)

Comment: You don't *have* to use `<cstdio>`. `<stdio.h>` is guaranteed to be provided by the C++ library (D.5). OK, it's deprecated, but in C++ deprecated means "required to be there by the current standard, but perhaps not by future standards". Conversely, features that are not deprecated are required to be there by the current standard, but perhaps not by future standards ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Interesting - do the `.h` headers also guarantee to put the symbols in the global namespace?

Comment: Yes, and it's unspecified whether they also go into `std`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for such a thing, g++ and gcc are just different frontends to the same compiler. So for all what concerns efficiency, byte compatability etc it should be no problem to mix `.o` files that are produced by both.

C and C++ have many subtle differences that can cause you trouble, starting from things such as `sizeof 'a'` beeing different but `sizeof c` being the same (if `c` is a `char`), to bool being a type in one and a macro in the other, `true` being of type `bool` in C++ and `int` in C, C not allowing `static` declarations in a `for` ...

And even if it is so that C and C++ have a large intersection, if you restrict yourself to what is considered good coding practice in both communities you quickly find that the intersection is almost empty. This concerns pointer casts, allocation with `malloc` or `new`, compound initializers versus constructors,  variable length arrays versus vector classes...

Just don't do it. All you need is to create a nice interface that is suitable for both.

Comment: The issues you cite are all red-herrings. Given how unintuitive it is (In my ignorance, I had to run a test to see what you were talking about.) `sizeof('a')` in a C program is likely to be a bug. Any C library that defines a bool type should have the good sense to `#ifdef __cplusplus ...` (my copy of `<stdbool.h>` does). Whether `true` is a `bool` or an `int` shouldn't affect the correctness of a program written for C unless someone is dumb enough to manipulate them with arithmetic operators (probably a bug). Finally, static declarations won't appear in `for` loops in a program written for C.

Comment: More to the point, running a code base intended for C — and using only C idioms — through a C++ compiler has very little downside. If you are that worried about silent bugs creeping in because someone wants to decrement a `bool` twice, simply test and release what the C compiler spits out.

Answer (score 0):

No, `g++` and `gcc` are not two different front-ends to the same compiler.

They are two different *drivers* for two different compilers (`cc1plus` and `cc1`) sharing the same middle-end and back-end code (withing GCC build-tree, inside `gcc/libbackend.a`, a misnomer, since it contains both middle-end (the middle-end is the common part of GCC, common to C, C++, Ada, Fortran, Objective-C, ... and many targets machines; it is the biggest part of GCC and work on a common set of internal representations, notably Gimple) and back-end (the part of GCC transforming Gimple representations to assembly, using RTL -a target dependent internal representation).

But cc1 and cc1plus have different front-end code.